# Error while trying to run an specific .deb file via terminal (Lubuntu 20.04)

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, deb, playonlinux

I have the .deb file of the newest version of PlayOnLinux and I can run it with no problems if I just double click it, but when I run it from terminal it gives an error and the program doesn't start.
Here is the command line output:

```
~$ ./Games/PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb 
./Games/PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./Games/PlayOnLinux_4.3.4.deb: line 1: `!<arch>'
```

The file is already tagged as executable in the properties.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: That's not how you installed debs. When you run `./someFile`, the default interpreter (or shell) tries to execute the "*file*" (unless it's a binary executable file or has shebang). Also, if you have already installed PlayOnLinux, it must appear in App drawer and you don't need to install again and again.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes, that answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: To install PlayOnLinux you do not need external deb-package. Use [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=PlayOnLinux) instead with same version: `sudo apt-add-repository multiverse; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install playonlinux` . It will satisfy all dependencies for you.

Comment: @N0rbert Good suggestion. I'm gonna use the repositories then.